# ReactJS TypeScript Mui Alert box message with href link

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

I have MUI Alert box in my application. I need to change inside message with href URL. when I set the `herf` tag it shows as text, I want to display it as link.

From the blow code, when I click Button, it display href as text. May I know how to display it as html link?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { Alert} from '@mui/material';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

export default function BasicAlerts() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('Form Loaded');

 // function to handle the click event on the link
  const handleLinkClick = () => {
    console.log("inside function")
    var u='<a href="https://www.google.com">Visit Google</a>'
    setMessage("changed : " +u)
  };

  return (
    <Stack sx={{ width: '100%' }} spacing={2}>
      
      <Alert variant="outlined" severity="info">
        This is an info alert — check it out!
        
         <Typography>
         <br/>
        {message}{' '}
        <br/>
       
      </Typography>
      </Alert>
      
       <Button onClick={handleLinkClick}>Change</Button>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Here is the code share link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-smoke-zjp82h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state is actually a string also on your click event your `setMessage("changed : " +u)` output is a string. so your anchor html is become an normal text under `<Typography />` tag.

You can set your `href` through your click event and based on your href you can show your output as an normal `typgraphy` or a anchor `link`.

For Example :

- For your click event action you can do something like this:

```
  const [href, setHref] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("Form Loaded");

  // function to handle the click event on the link
  const handleLinkClick = () => {
    console.log("inside function");
    var url = "https://google.com";
    setHref(url);
    setMessage("visit Google");
  };
```

- and for rendering the changes on event action :

```
      <Alert variant="outlined" severity="info">
        This is an info alert — check it out!
        <Typography>
          <br />
          {href ? (
            <a id="anchor" href={href}>
              {message}
            </a>
          ) : (
            message
          )}
        </Typography>
      </Alert>
```

Comment: code : https://codesandbox.io/embed/gracious-chatterjee-u7gn92?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark